# How to build a binary tree without using the 'L' and 'R' direction array

Tags: c++, c

I want to build a binary tree(not a BST) without using an array with has left and right directions instructions. Because, it strictly wouldnt make the tree a dynamic allocation one. You would be restricted by the size of the array. Can any one thing of a way out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Umm, just don't use an array. What do you need an array for anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question, but if it's **binary** it doesn't make sense to ask for a tree whose number of children (per node) can dynamically increase or decrease.

However, if that's what you need, instead of storing the pointers to the children in a simple array, use a list.